# How Can I Measure Firestore Response Time?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching data that is stored in Firestore to use in my web app. Normally to check the speed of this kind of call, I'd just check the network tab in the chrome dev tools.

But for my Firebase Query, in the network tab it always shows a time of 1 minute (I've learned this is because of the open long polling connection that the JavaScript SDK utilizes).

[image: Network tab screenshot]

So is there a way where I can get more specific details on the speed of my Firestore response?

Comment: Are you referring to listeners or one time requests ? [Firebase Performance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon) for web is in beta but that may be useful.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I'm referring to a one time request.

Comment: You can try Firebase Performance and/or [performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) which is built-in of browsers.

Comment: Hi there! could you please tell me if Firebase Performence or the buil-in of browser worked for you?